# Spring boot Quartz to skip some jobs

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I use spring boot + maven multi module project. I am using cluster-aware Quartz configuration, so job details are stored in the database. Lets say, 2 Spring boot maven modules (projects) are using quartz, but I want each module run it is own jobs, which are different to each module. In that case, when I start one module, it actually tries to run jobs from other module too because Quartz engine is reading the jobs to run from the database. So how do I specify in each module to run only specific jobs related to at module?
One way is to have different table prefixes for each module. Is there any other way to use the same quartz tables between 2 different modules, but each module decide which jobs to run?

Answer (score 0):

I have almost the same. My solution was:
Job A writes a flag into the DB table next to the job "running_by" jobA and when its done, it remove the flag.

So JobB checks if this Job has a flag already. If not it will proceed, if yes it skip this job because JobA is already running it.

Answer (score -1):

config a property in quartz.properties
`org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true`
that can make quartz work in cluster mode

Comment: Sorry, this answer has nothing to do with my question.  My jobs are saved in db already, so it is cluster aware

Comment: Each module uses its own database

Comment: that is not my requirement